# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'slice'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

The code used to import the keras model is [model.py](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14FDdGJscp4pk6PxlU_lRTExBBkS1vn5z/view?usp=sharing)

Complete error traceback can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mw6rpbln5FtYxphy0MdBR5A3j72Bz3x4/view?usp=sharing)

```
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in get_slice(data, i, parts)
        193   
        194 
    --> 195   def __init__(self, rate, noise_shape=None, seed=None, **kwargs):
        196     super(Dropout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        197     self.rate = rate
    
    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'slice'
```

Line 195 in the core.py file has no function get_slice and
Also unable to trace the file to update slice to tf.slice as suggested by mulitple individuals on the overflow.
**Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?**

Comment: You need to provide a full piece of code and the full error traceback. The line of code the arrow points to has nothing to do with the error. Also, as it is, we cannot tell if this problem is with user-defined code, a library you downloaded, TF itself...

Comment: Added the links for both the code and the error traceback.

Comment: Can you share `LB_potato.h5` file and all other required files to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NLU61iZ08rnjPgvfnhahj1iPzoHgLiLD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @TFer2 I have attached the link for the model and I just want to load and run the model. Unfortunately I have no other files related to it.